# Adding beep on key press in Android doesn't work

Tags: android

In my `Custom IME` I want to play a `BEEP` sound on the key when user presses that.

I found [how-do-i-access-androids-default-beep-sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462105/how-do-i-access-androids-default-beep-sound) , and in my `SoftKeyboard.java` class I added that code in :

```
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    // play sound on keypress
    try {
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.beep);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

BUT that does not work, any ideas why?

Comment: Most probably, default notification ringtone is not set (yet). Are you testing this on an emulator?

Comment: @shoerat Yes I m testing on emulator

Comment: Also, please don't swallow exceptions like that, if something goes wrong, you won't know it - add e.printStackTrace() inside your catch()

Comment: That's your problem. Test on a real device or set notification ringtone.

Comment: @shoerat how can I set that one! please guide me if?

Comment: @shoerat please see my edit, that still not work....

Comment: @Melquiades please see my edit, that still not work.

Comment: `that still not work` - is onKeyDown() ever called? What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't have idea, because I'm unable to debug that :-(

Comment: @Melquiades after new `Edit`, I'm getting this stack trace `02-21 18:39:09.940: E/MediaPlayer(20950): prepareAsync called in state 8`

Comment: Remove mediaPlayer.prepare(), it's not needed when you create MediaPlayer with create().

Comment: Post an answer of what needed to be done to make it work and accept it, so that others don't have to go through these long comments to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling mMediaPlayer.prepare() unnecessarily, as it's not needed when creating MediaPlayer with it's create() method. This is the solution which worked for me

```
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    // play sound on keypress
    try {
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.beep);

        mMediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```