# ListView: how to notify the user about new fetched data with sound and vibration?

Tags: android, listview

I've added my MainActivity below, the application fetches data from a database and refreshes automatically and on swipe down.

**My question is, how on earth can it notify the user about "new" fetched inserts via sound and vibration?**

*To be more specific regarding the definition of "new inserts", the application starts with 0 data in it, once refreshed a php call from the database gets a new JSON string and is decoded in the app and appears on the listview.*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

        private int mInterval = 5000; // 5 seconds by default, can be changed later
        private Handler mHandler;

        private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private String URL = "http://10.0.0.2:0080/stringtest2.php?offset=";


        private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
        private ListView listView;
        private SwipeListAdapter adapter;
        private List<Order> orderList;

        // initially offset will be 0, later will be updated while parsing the json
        private int offSet = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_description = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50,10);

            //Rl.setLayoutParams(layout_description);

            swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

            orderList = new ArrayList<>();
            adapter = new SwipeListAdapter(this, orderList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

            /**
             * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
             * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
             */
            swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                            fetchOrders();
                                        }
                                    }
            );

            mHandler = new Handler();
            startRepeatingTask();
        }



        /**
         * This method is called when swipe refresh is pulled down
         */



    Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //updateStatus(); //this function can change value of mInterval.
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
        }
    };
        void startRepeatingTask() {
            mStatusChecker.run();
        }

        void stopRepeatingTask() {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
        }

    //added code start here
    Runnable mAutoRefreshRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fetchOrders();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mAutoRefreshRunnable, 60000);
        }
    };

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mAutoRefreshRunnable, 60000);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mAutoRefreshRunnable);
        }
        //added code ends here


        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            fetchOrders();
        }

        /**
         * Fetching movies json by making http call
         */
        private void fetchOrders() {

            // showing refresh animation before making http call
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

            // appending offset to url
            String url = URL + offSet;

            // Volley's json array request object
            JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                            if (response.length() > 0) {

                                // looping through json and adding to order list
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject orderObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                        int rank = orderObj.getInt("rank");
                                        String title = orderObj.getString("title");

                                        Order m = new Order(rank, title);

                                        orderList.add(0, m);

                                        // updating offset value to highest value
                                        if (rank >= offSet)
                                            offSet = rank;

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                }

                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            // stopping swipe refresh
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't connect to database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // stopping swipe refresh
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you fetch new data, there is a place you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to let the listview update its content.

right after that call, you can use Vibrator to start a vibration

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
 v.vibrate(500);
```

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html

To play sound, you need a MediaPlayer:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, yourSoundFile);
mp.start();
```

Comment: Hey yongsunCN thanks for your reply, I'm really new to android, can you show me via the MainActivity I've added where exactly to implement that, and is there any default soundfile to enter just for the example?

Comment: In you fetchOrders() method, you have adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after this line you add above code, a simple way to add media file is put your media file(for example called soho.mp3) under the raw folder (if not found then create one) under your resource directory, then use MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);

Comment: just added the vibrator code beneath the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); line, and the application crashed :/

Comment: can you provide more detail? what does the log say?

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission , grrrr permission......

Comment: its working I've added permission - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />