# How to double beep with ToneGenerator

Tags: java, android, audio, kotlin, tone-generator

### The problem

I've been trying to achieve a double beep sound on an app I'm developing once a button is pressed.

Problem is, I didn't manage to get it quite right. Sometimes the sounds overlapped, other times they played faster than they should.

I wanted to play an arbitrary tone, have an arbitrary pause/delay and then play the tone again.

**OBS**: [I've seen some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462105/how-do-i-access-androids-default-beep-sound) for this problem using the `MediaPlayer` or the `Ringtone` class, but this question is on how to achieve this using `ToneGenerator` only, without using the `TONE_PROP_BEEP2` or `TONE_PROP_ACK` tones.

### What I've tried so far

First of all, I tried to call the `startTone()` method twice, but soon I found out that the sounds played simultaneously.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val toneG = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100)
    toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200)
    toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200)
}
```

Then I tried to use `Handler` in two ways.

First I tried to use two of them:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val toneG = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100)
    val handler = Handler()

    handler.postDelayed({
        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200)
    }, 50)
    handler.postDelayed({
        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200)
    }, 350)
}
```

Second, I also tried with `Thread.sleep()`:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val toneG = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100)
    val handler = Handler()

    handler.postDelayed({
        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200)
        Thread.sleep(100)
        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200)
    }, 50)
}
```

Both ideas "kinda" worked. But on the first button press, the beeps sounded funny, as they played way too fast, and sometimes even overlapping.

The second time I pressed the `Button`, the tones played correctly.

Comment: How can I single beep as Long ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) and see if it works better.
I actually tried your first option and did not notice the affect you mentioned. I am not sure [postDelayed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) makes any promises other than ***"Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses"*** , you could also try `postAtTime()` instead of `postDelayed()`

```
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val toneG = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100)
        val timer = object: CountDownTimer(350,50) {

            var skipThisInterval = false

            override fun onFinish() {
                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200)
            }

            override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                if (skipThisInterval) return
                skipThisInterval = true
                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200)
            }
        }
        timer.start()

    }
```

using `postAtTime()` rather than `postDelayed()` might work better also.

```
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val toneG = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100)
        val handler = Handler()
        val timeNow = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

        handler.postAtTime({
            toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200)
        }, 50 + timeNow)
        handler.postAtTime({
            toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200)
        }, 350 + timeNow)
    }
```

Comment: I will try your solution, thanks! As for the effect I said. I only tested it on one device, I might try on others to see if it persists. But it was really weird to only happen on the first run.

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me:

```
val tg = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 1000)
tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val toneGen1 = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100)
                toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP, 150)
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    val toneGen1 = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100)
                    toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP, 150)
                }, 150)
```