# Display notification about received SMS message

Tags: android, sms, android-notifications

I'm creating an SMS message inside Inbox folder as follows:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", sender);
values.put("date", System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put("read", 0); // Message not read
values.put("status", 0);
values.put("type", 1);
values.put("seen", 0);
values.put("body", body);

ContentResolver rslv = context.getContentResolver();        
rslv.insert(Uri.parse("content://sms"), values);
```

This works well, but doesn't fire the usual "SMS received" notification in the top bar and play the notfitication sound. 
How do I do write such notification code (which presumably calls some SMS application's Intent to raise the notification) ?

Comment: where is Notification code..??

Comment: I dont have any so far, because I have no idea how to do this. It about using the SMS application's internal notification right?

Comment: as you are creating SMS at inbox so you need to Notification code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a notification is done by using [`Notification.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) class. A really simple example is this:

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New SMS from " + sender.toString())
         .setContentText(subject) 
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setLargeIcon(aBitmap) 
         .build();
```

More information is available in the [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) for the same.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Does it also play the sound? I need to get as close to the actual SMS notification as possible for the convenience.

Comment: @NumberFour Have a look at the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441334/how-to-play-an-android-notification-sound). Anything else I can help you with?

Comment: Ok, I have one more question :) Where do I get the `R.drawable.new_mail` and the common icons, is it the android support library? Or do I have to add my own one?

Comment: @NumberFour Add your own. :) It is simply `R.drawable` and not `android.R.drawable` so you can see that it is specific to the app and not in the standard library :)