# Play Android default sound effect

Tags: android, audio, effect

Is there a way to play built-in sound effects programmatically? I want to play the NFC sound effect when my app scans an NFC tag (success sound effect and failure sound effect).

Answer (score 2):

Im just pasting code from the accepted answer that is in - [StackOverflow question to play Android Notification sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441334/how-to-play-an-android-notification-sound)

```
try {
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How would I play the NFC sound effect?