# How to play a sound (produced in an app) on incoming message/notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, ringtone

I would like to play a sound (which I generate in a standalone app) when an event/notification occurs, like an incoming message or a notification from a game. For example: I receive a message in Telegram and the OS proceeds to "play the ringtone" (but it instead runs my sound-generating app).

I thought this behavior would require some interaction with the OS in order to "redirect" the default action of playing a ringtone's file to my app, so I could generate my sound and play it. But it's just a theory. xD :P

I searched in Google, but nothing showed up. :( I have made apps for Android, but in this issue I really have no clue of how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance for any help provided! :D

Answer (score 0):

From: [How to play an android notification sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441334/how-to-play-an-android-notification-sound)

```
try {
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can change TYPE_NOTIFICATION to TYPE_ALARM, but you'll want to keep track of your Ringtone r in order to stop playing it... say, when the user clicks a button or something.

Also here's a link that maybe can help you solve your [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for your help! :D But I'm afraid it won't do the trick. :( I added more info to the question description to clarify what I would like to do.