# Firebase cloud function send notification to all users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a notification to all users of my app whenever there is a write on the database.

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
export const newUserAdded = functions.database
                        .ref('1_0_0/updateDate/date')
                        .onWrite((event)=>{
                            //send notfigication to all 
                            admin.messaging().sendToCondition()
                        })
```

As you can see whenever there is a write to the `date` key the function will trigger.

But note here that I do not have device token of the user as I want to send a notification to all users. I was not able to find any method do so.

Kindly do let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging).  Arrange for all your client apps to subscribe to a dedicated, named topic for broadcasting to all app installations, then send your message to that topic.

Comment: any examples of that in js/angular?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging

Comment: yeah I did. Thanks. But need more of example like in codelabs. Will try out the docs. thanks

Comment: I got it to work with subscribing to topic. But no sound is played when  notification arrives. Any payload data changes to be made there?

Comment: You can't control that with a notification payload.  If you want to control the notification, use a data payload and handle the incoming payload yourself.

Comment: for the sound https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441334/how-to-play-an-android-notification-sound