# allow sound on default permission settings on android oreo and higher

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I'm working on an android app where I need to display notifications to user.
The problem is the notification sound is not played. vibration is working fine though.
When check the app settings the 'allow sound' option is disabled by default. As I enable it, everything works fine. however i need it to be enabled by default.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1AXJ.jpg)

These two permissions do exists in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

and here is the code snippet i use to create the notification channel and display notification.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, title,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();
        channel.setSound(alarmSound, attributes);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.enableVibration(true);

        ((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{500L,500L,500L})
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentText(stringBuilder.toString().trim()).build();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622040/12272687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution to activate 'allow sound' by default.
But this workaround did the job.

After I display the notification, I do this to play the notification sound independently.

```
try {
      Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
      Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
      r.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If this workaround solved your problem, then mark it as accepted to help others know it

Comment: @Mohammad yes. it solved my problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622040/12272687