# android: play sound from sdk

Tags: android, audio, playback

I want to know if there are some sounds in the android sdk that I could play in my app. I need something like the sound played when I receive a sms message or something like that (a ding).

If there is a sound, how can I get it?

I saw the fallbackring.ogg in the raw package from android sdk but I can't access it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spend some time reading this discussion: [how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android)

Hope this helps.