# What is wrong with the code

Tags: android

I have written PhoneStateListener which listens for telephony events through broadcast receiver. I am receiving following error on `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`

> 06-10 13:50:48.360:
>   VERBOSE/ERROR(4686): URI:
>   content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup/,
>   calling user: com.emergency.alert,
>   calling package:com.emergency.alert

Code is Listed below

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public Context context;
    //private static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private Uri alert;
    private static Uri prev_ringtone;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "ealertprefs";
    public static int phone_state;
    public EmergencyAdapter dbHelper;   
    private String fetchName;
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            try {
                if(call_from_elist(incomingNumber)) {                   
                    retrieve_phone();                       
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.v("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }
            Log.v("CALL", "IDLE");
        break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:                                   
                //retrieve_phone();                                 
        break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
          if(call_from_elist(incomingNumber)) {
              set_uri();
              wake_up_phone();
              send_notification();                       
          }       
        break;
        }
    }
    private void retrieve_phone() {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);        
        am.setRingerMode(phone_state);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, prev_ringtone);
    }
    private boolean call_from_elist(String number) {
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                PhoneLookup._ID,
                PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };

        // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

        // query time
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

        // if the query returns 1 or more results
        // return the first result
        Log.v("ELIST", "LOG");
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.v("ELIST", "LOG2");
            String _id = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            dbHelper = new EmergencyAdapter(context);
            dbHelper.open();
            Log.v("CALLER", _id);
            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchEntry_call(Long.parseLong(_id));
            Log.v("CALLER", ""+cursor.getCount());
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {             
                fetchName = cursor.getString(1);
                Log.v("CALLER", fetchName);         
                return true;
            }
            else {              
                return false;
            }           
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void wake_up_phone() {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        phone_state = am.getRingerMode();
        Log.v("WAKEUP", Integer.toString(phone_state));
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, alert);
        am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);        

    }
    private void send_notification(){
        NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);                
        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon,"Simple Notification",System.currentTimeMillis());        
        Intent toLaunch = new Intent(context, main.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, toLaunch, 0);        
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Emergency Alert", "Emergency call received from "+fetchName, contentIntent);        
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;                              
        notifier.notify(0x007, notification);
    }
    private void set_uri() {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String ringtone = settings.getString("call_uri", "");
        if(ringtone.equals("")) {
            this.alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        else {
            this.alert = Uri.parse(ringtone);
        }        
        prev_ringtone = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    }
}
```

This error only occurs on TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE case. Please provide any solution to this problem.

Stack Trace is

> 06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   URI:
>   content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup/,
>   calling user: com.emergency.alert,
>   calling package:com.emergency.alert
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:372)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:408)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:264)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   com.emergency.alert.MyPhoneStateListener.call_from_elist(MyPhoneStateListener.java:72)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   com.emergency.alert.MyPhoneStateListener.onCallStateChanged(MyPhoneStateListener.java:36)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:391)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   06-10 15:32:39.332:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)

Comment: Try adding the actual exception to your Log.v() calls as it will dump full details of the exception being thrown to LogCat: Log.v( "TAG", "Where it was caught", e ); Then provide the LogCat of the stack trace that gets dumped when a failure occurs.

Comment: I have posted stack trace, please take a look at it and let me know if you figure out something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your problem is that when you're receiving CALL_STATE_IDLE, the incomingNumber variable is not set because there isn't an active or ringing call, and therefore no phone number associated with the current phone state. You're then doing a contacts lookup which is failing because you are not including a valid phone number in the query.

So you're trying to lookup a contact when you don't actually have a phone number to search on.

Comment: Thanks so the solution is to set phone number in local static variable at Ringing State?

Comment: No, because there is no phone number associated with CALL_STATE_IDLE, so doing a lookup of the currently active caller when there is no active call doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I've seen this error before,

your URI is malformed as you are setting it to the default ringtone

```
 prev_ringtone = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
```

However the default ringtone has not been set so your getting back a blank string / null or some other error.

check this question and answer for clarity: [How to play ringtone/alarm sound in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android/5687023#5687023)