# How to play ringtone once through MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, loops, uri, media-player, ringtone

I can't play a ringtone once even if mediaplayer looping property is set to false. It looks like this property was overriden by the ringtone `URI`used. So `onCompletion` is never fired.

Curiously, if the `URI` corresponds to a notification tone, looping behaves according to `setLooping`. It works well here.

So is there a way to play a ringtone once?

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before and solved it by using OnSeekCompleteListener:

`mMediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new OnSeekCompleteListener() {
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Your stuff
}});`

I don't know if it's the best way to solve this, but it worked for me.

Edit: BTW, I use both listeners, oncompletionlistener AND onseekcompletelistener. Hope this helps!