# How to use Device built in Ringtones in my android Application?

Tags: android, ringtone

I done a sample application to show a bundle of images is as slide show. Here i need to play a sound track in background when the slide will get change. Here my problem is, i **must play device in built** audio files (Ringtones). How can i get device in built Ringtones list. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried this case ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android

Comment: @Yahor10: Yes, i tried but i can't get all ringtones list