# How to play ringtone sound in Android with infinite loop?

Tags: android, android-notifications, ringtone

i want to play the ringtone selected in the settings of the device, but in loop mode.

here you can see how to play it only once: [How to play ringtone/alarm sound in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android)

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
r.play();
```

I need to make it play in loop mode, but i don't know how to do it...

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems the simplest way is to create a `MediaPlayer` from the `Uri` returned from `RingtoneManager`, and set it to loop.

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, notification);
player.setLooping(true);
player.start();
```

Comment: Works fine, but how to stop that loop then ?

Comment: Call `player.stop()`.

Answer (score 2):

By using setLooping(true) you can achieve this:

```
Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Please also provide some explanation for your answer to show how it solves the problem.