# How to set sound/ringtone/alarm for particular text?

Tags: android

I'm creating a ride making app, In that app i need to set alarm / ringtone sound for particular text

```
 public class RefreshReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.package.ACTION_CLASS_TrackYourRide_REFRESH_Arrived_Driver")) {
            System.out.println("triparrived----------------------");
            Tv_headerTitle.setText("Driver Arrived");
            rl_endTrip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            track_your_ride_view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals("com.package.ACTION_CLASS_TrackYourRide_REFRESH_BeginTrip")){
                System.out.println("tripbegin----------------------");
            Tv_headerTitle.setText("Enjoy the RYDD");
            rl_endTrip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            track_your_ride_view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            panic_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

In that above code ,set alarm , when driver arrived text came. How to set sound for particular text when app is in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at [How to play ringtone/alarm sound in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android)

```
try {
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I know about this but how to set ringtone for particular word("Driver Arrived").

Comment: set the ringtone for that particular condition    if (intent.getAction().equals("com.package.ACTION_CLASS_TrackYourRide_REFRESH_Arrived_Driver"))