# Cannot play default notification ringtone on some device

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-contentresolver

Here is my code snippet to play ringtone notification:

```
Uri u = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(MainActivity.this, u);
r.play();
```

This seems to work fine on most devices. However, on some devices such as Samsung S8 and Samsung S9, it does not work. Logcat shows:

```
I/Ringtone: Internal uri : content://settings/system/notification_sound
D/RingtoneManager: getActualDefaultRingtoneUri  type    :2
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open content://0@settings/system/notification_sound_cache: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Note that the same code works fine on Samsung S7.

Wondering if anyone has any insight.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android