# android how to play a beep at a certain frequency

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to play a beep at a specified frequency for a specified length of time. How is this achieved in android? I noticed that their is an AudioTrack api but they don't provide any easy examples on its usage.

Answer (score 0):

[Soundpool Android Dev](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool)

Put the audio in the raw folder

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
int soundId = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.beep, 1);
// soundId for reuse later on

soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
//(soundId , LEFT_VOLUME_VALUE , RIGHT_VOLUME_VALUE, SOUND_PLAY_PRIORITY , MUSIC_LOOP ,PLAY_RATE)
```

Use the PLAY_RATE  attribute to change the frequency of the music being played

and use the MUSIC_LOOP to determine how many times it plays

Comment: I'm wanting to create the beep programmatically as it is dynamic and frequency and duration vary. Does android not offer that feature?

Comment: This requires an audio file though doesn't it? I'm trying to generate the sound programmatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2618182/13533028  This should help you out make sure you're using an actual device and not an emulator

Comment: Unfortuantley that doesn't let me specify the frequency in hz