# Make sound alarm on object detection application

Tags: java, android, opencv, audio, object-detection

I want to make an object detection app with sound alarm when I detect on specific objects.
I first want to try with tutorial https://github.com/bendahouwael/Vehicle-Detection-App-Android. This code is an application that detects car.

First I want to make sound alarm when it detects car. Have any ideas?
Here's the code about `objectDetectorClass.java` in that github link.

```
package com.example.imagepro;

import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.A;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class objectDetectorClass {
    private Interpreter interpreter;
    private List<String> labelList;
    private int INPUT_SIZE;
    private int PIXEL_SIZE=3;
    private int IMAGE_MEAN=0;
    private  float IMAGE_STD=255.0f;
    private GpuDelegate gpuDelegate;
    private int height=0;
    private  int width=0;

    objectDetectorClass(AssetManager assetManager,String modelPath, String labelPath,int inputSize) throws IOException{
        INPUT_SIZE=inputSize;
        Interpreter.Options options=new Interpreter.Options();
        gpuDelegate=new GpuDelegate();
        options.addDelegate(gpuDelegate);
        options.setNumThreads(4);
        interpreter=new Interpreter(loadModelFile(assetManager,modelPath),options);
        labelList=loadLabelList(assetManager,labelPath);
    }

    private List<String> loadLabelList(AssetManager assetManager, String labelPath) throws IOException {
        List<String> labelList=new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open(labelPath)));
        String line;
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null ){

            labelList.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return labelList;
    }

    private ByteBuffer loadModelFile(AssetManager assetManager, String modelPath) throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor=assetManager.openFd(modelPath);
        FileInputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel=inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset =fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength=fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();

        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,startOffset,declaredLength);
    }
    public Mat recognizeImage(Mat mat_image){
        Mat rotated_mat_image=new Mat();
        Core.flip(mat_image.t(),rotated_mat_image,1);
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(rotated_mat_image.cols(),rotated_mat_image.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(rotated_mat_image,bitmap);
        height=bitmap.getHeight();
        width=bitmap.getWidth();
         Bitmap scaledBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,INPUT_SIZE,INPUT_SIZE,false);
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer=convertBitmapToByteBuffer(scaledBitmap);
        Object[] input=new Object[1];
        input[0]=byteBuffer;
        Map<Integer,Object> output_map=new TreeMap<>();
        float[][][]boxes =new float[1][10][4];
        float[][] scores=new float[1][10];
        float[][] classes=new float[1][10];
        output_map.put(0,boxes);
        output_map.put(1,classes);
        output_map.put(2,scores);
        interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(input,output_map);
        Object value=output_map.get(0);
        Object Object_class=output_map.get(1);
        Object score=output_map.get(2);
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            float class_value=(float) Array.get(Array.get(Object_class,0),i);
            float score_value=(float) Array.get(Array.get(score,0),i);
            if(score_value>0.5){
                Object box1=Array.get(Array.get(value,0),i);
                float top=(float) Array.get(box1,0)*height;
                float left=(float) Array.get(box1,1)*width;
                float bottom=(float) Array.get(box1,2)*height;
                float right=(float) Array.get(box1,3)*width;
                if(class_value==2 || class_value==3 || class_value==5 || class_value==7 ){
                Imgproc.rectangle(rotated_mat_image,new Point(left,top),new Point(right,bottom),new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255),2);
                Imgproc.putText(rotated_mat_image,labelList.get((int) class_value),new Point(left,top),3,1,new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255),2);}
            }

        }
        Core.flip(rotated_mat_image.t(),mat_image,0);
        return mat_image;
    }

    private ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer;

        int quant=0;
        int size_images=INPUT_SIZE;
        if(quant==0){
            byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1*size_images*size_images*3);
        }
        else {
            byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*1*size_images*size_images*3);
        }
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        int[] intValues=new int[size_images*size_images];
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
        int pixel=0;
        for (int i=0;i<size_images;++i){
            for (int j=0;j<size_images;++j){
                final  int val=intValues[pixel++];
                if(quant==0){
                    byteBuffer.put((byte) ((val>>16)&0xFF));
                    byteBuffer.put((byte) ((val>>8)&0xFF));
                    byteBuffer.put((byte) (val&0xFF));
                }
                else {
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((((val) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                }
            }
        }
    return byteBuffer;
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Ok, what's the problem with this code?

Comment: The code I uploaded works fine about object detection. My question is which code I have to put in to make sound alarm when detecting car.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play ringtone/alarm sound in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android)

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't help me. What I want is when car is detected, it just plays a bit of sound. I think ```mediaPlayer``` fits to mine so I followed the way you linked. But doesn't make any sound.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any solution below once you have detected a car from your image.

> To sound an alarm

```
 try {
       val uri: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM)
       val r: Ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(applicationContext, uri)
       r.play()
     } catch (e: Exception) {
       e.printStackTrace()
     }
```

> For a short beep

```
ToneGenerator(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, 200).also {
            it.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_EMERGENCY_RINGBACK)
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell me where do I have to put the second code to my code I uploaded? Thank you!